# how to center multicolumn content keeping columns aligned left

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have three columns, aligned left, and need all distances to be the same:
- distances between columns
- left-right distances regarding the parent.

```
<div id="linkswrap">
<a class="link">123</a>
<a class="link">1234</a>
<a class="link">12345</a>
<a class="link">123456</a>
<a class="link">1234567</a>
<a class="link">12345678</a>
<a class="link">123456789</a>
</div>
```

css

```
#linkswrap{
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    text-align:center;
    background:green;
}
.link{
  display:block;
  text-align:left;
  color:#ffffff;
}
```

I tried with `text-align:center` on `linkswrap` - doesn't work.

Also, if I say `text-align:center` on `link` the columns become centered itself, but I need links inside columns to stay aligned left;

jsfiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bonaca/8q2f8q4o/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `text-indent:36%;` to do this. :)

```
text-indent: 36%;
```

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/8q2f8q4o/2/)